# Calcular horas en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Quiero saber si hay alguna función en sql server que me calcule cuántas horas hay en un intervalo dado, es decir que teniendo una tabla como la siguiente:

[image: start]

Donde start, end y break son dados, calcule el total para cada columna (empleado)

Actualmente éste cálculo lo hago con php, recorriendo la tabla y extrayendo los valores respectivos de cada empleado:

```
function hourdiff($hour_1, $hour_2, $break_minutes){

    $h1_explode = explode(":" , $hour_1);
    $h2_explode = explode(":" , $hour_2);

    $h1_explode[0] = (int) $h1_explode[0];
    $h1_explode[1] = (int) $h1_explode[1];
    $h2_explode[0] = (int) $h2_explode[0];
    $h2_explode[1] = (int) $h2_explode[1];

    $h1_to_minutes = ($h1_explode[0] * 60) + $h1_explode[1];
    $h2_to_minutes = ($h2_explode[0] * 60) + $h2_explode[1];

    if($h1_to_minutes > $h2_to_minutes){
        $subtraction = $h1_to_minutes - $h2_to_minutes;
    }
    else {
        $subtraction = $h2_to_minutes - $h1_to_minutes;
    }

    $result = $subtraction / 60;
    if($break_minutes != NULL)
        $result = ($subtraction - $break_minutes)/60;

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Hola para poder ayudarte tienes que compartir tú código, mostrarnos donde te lanza error que has intentado. Te invito ha hacer un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y sobre cualquier duda puedes visitar esta [sección de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Suerte

Comment: Para realizar resta entre fecha y que te retorne horas, existe una funcion **SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '2005-12-30 00:00:00', '2005-12-31 02:00:00');**, mayor información en el siguiente https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola creo que te puede servir lo siguiente(siempre y cuando los valores de horas los calculas de un **DATETIME** ya que no pones la consulta):

Utiliza el comando **DATEDIFF** el cual te brinda la diferencia de tiempo entre dos campos de fecha diferentes la sintaxis es de la siguiente manera.

```
DATEDIFF ( "TIPO" , "FECHAINI" , "FECHAFIN" )
```

Donde **"TIPO"** puede ser:

-Año, Abreviatura(aa, aaaa) (Usar años de cuatro dígitos para evitar ambigüedad)

-Trimestre, Abreviatura(tt, t)

-Mes, Abreviatura(mm, m)

-Dia del año, Abreviatura(da, a)

-Día, Abreviatura(dd, d)

-Semana, Abreviatura(sm, ss)

-Hora, Abreviatura(hh)

-Minuto, Abreviatura(mi, n)

-Segundo, Abreviatura(ss, s)

-Milisegundo, Abreviatura(Ms)

Saludos espero te sirva.